Supertest and Sinon - stubbing same function twice (or more)
I'm unable to user supertest with sinon to stub the same function twice in the same test file. How can I do this?
Here is the code I have currently:
const { app } = require('../../app');
const request = require('supertest');
const sinon = require('sinon');
const { expect } = require('chai');
const testConfig = require('../testConfig/testConfig');
const utils = require('../../helpers/utils');

const token = testConfig.token;
const header = { 'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}` };


const mockOrder = {
   accountNumber: '1234',
   orderSourceId: 1
}

const mockOrders = [mockOrder];



describe('Vendors routes', () => {

   afterEach(() => {
      sinon.restore();
   })


   describe('GET /orders/:accountNumber', () => {

      it('should get an order record for provided Account Number', async () => {
         sinon.stub(utils, 'getOrder').resolves(mockOrders);
         const accountNumber = '1234';

         const route = testConfig.createRoute(`/vendors/orders/${accountNumber}`);
         const res = await request(app)
            .get(route)
            .set(header);

         expect(res.status).to.be.equal(200);
      })


      it('should return 404 if an order is not found', async () => {
         sinon.stub(utils, 'getOrder').resolves(undefined);
         const accountNumber = '1234';

         const route = testConfig.createRoute(`/vendors/orders/${accountNumber}`);
         const res = await request(app)
            .get(route)
            .set(header);

         expect(res.status).to.be.equal(404);
         sinon.restore();

      })
   })
})

As you can see from above, I simply want to adjust what the function getOrder resolves to. However I get the following error when doing this with supertest:
Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.
The first test will pass, but the second one fails. Why is sinon not able to overwrite the stubbed function more than once? What's going on exactly?

We need to see the code under test.

Use ${mockOrder.accountNumber} instead of constant const accountNumber = '1234'; in order to avoid duplication.
